# Solving a ODE using series

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove that the series
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(n!)^{2}}$$
satisfies the ODE
$$xy''+y'-y=0$$
When I derivate and substitute in the equation, I get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}x^{n-1}-x^{n}}{(n!)^{2}}=0$$
What I suppose to do now?

Comment: See [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). This is simply $I_0\big(2\sqrt x\big)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$x^k$" term of $xy'' + y'$ is obtained by differentiating the term $\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$. And we get $\frac{(k+1)^2}{((k+1)!)^2}x^k$. By cancellation, this is $\frac{1}{(k!)^2}x^k$.  Now subtract the $x^k$ term in the expansion of $y$. This is $\frac{1}{(k!)^2} x^k$. Thus $xy''+y'-y$ has series expansion $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 0\cdot x^k$.

Alternately, the expansion of $xy''+y'$ is $\sum_0^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n!)^2}x^{n-1}$. By cancellation, this is $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{((n-1)!)^2} x^{n-1}$. The term $n=0$ gives $0$. So replace $n-1$ by $n$. We get $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{((n!)^2}x^n$. Finally, subtract $y$. Everything cancels.

Comment: But shouldn't I do like this: $y''=\sum\frac{n(n-1)x^{n-2}}{(n!)^{2}}$, then $xy''=\sum\frac{n(n-1)x^{n-1}}{(n!)^{2}}$?

Comment: Yes, you did that correctly. Then when you add the $y'$ part, you get $\frac{n^2}{(n!)^2}x^{n-1}$, which simplifies to $\frac{1}{((n-1)!)^2}x^{n-1}$. Now **subtract** the term in $x^{n-1}$ in the expansion of $y$. This term is $\frac{1}{((n-1)!)^2}x^{n-1}$. So the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the expansion of $xy''+y'-y$ is $0$. That is basically what I did, using $k$ instead of $n-1$.

Comment: Now I got. Thanks ;)

Comment: You are welcome. In your first post, you had a $+$ instead of a $-$. That probably prevented you from seeing how when we take account of indices, everything cancels.